# opencart installation issue on step 3 windows

Tags: php

i cannot install opencart on third step.i have the following problem:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   C:\wamp\www\opencart\upload\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line
>   7Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\wamp\www\opencart\upload\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line
>   10Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\wamp\www\opencart\upload\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line
>   10Notice: Undefined variable: mysql in
>   C:\wamp\www\opencart\upload\install\controller\install\step_3.php on
>   line 280Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\opencart\upload\install\controller\install\step_3.php on
>   line 280

php× 1144494

Comment: username/password for database is wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328153/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: i wrote admin admin

Comment: what should i write?

Comment: Allesandro tell me how to fix it

Comment: Your `host : localhost , DBusername : root` and password should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is getting same type of error ,you could try out this,

username=admin

password=

keep your password null

The reason this might happened is because of password you gave in phpmyadmin during setting time.